# Should Greek or Norse mythology be used?

Tags: fantasy, mythology

When writing, what of these two mythologies should be used, in terms of quality and preservation of the original sources? (I am not listing other mythologies like Aztec, Mesopotamian, Caribbean, Polynesian etc because they are not well known or familiar to most readers)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I think by preservation of the original sources you are meaning which mythology is better documented. If that is so then the Greeks would win since more of their writings were preserved. There are complete copies of Greek plays -- complete with dialogue and chorus. But the word 'should' makes the question confusing since there is no reason any mythology ought to be a better basis for a story than any other mythology.

Comment: I would argue that "not well known or familiar to most readers" is a benefit, not a drawback. At this point I feel like I've read a thousand stories relying heavily on Greek mythology. I would welcome a story involving a lesser-known-to-me mythology!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It ultimately depends on your personal preference.**

There is a wealth of lore from both Norse and Greek mythologies. I'd recommend you do some research on your own to determine which best fits your story. I think (in my uneducated opinion) that Greek myths are better known and thus have been preserved more deeply than Nordic myths. However, there are plenty of stories in each.

This might also help: https://viking.style/norse-mythology-vs-greek-mythology/

No one can tell you which better suits your writing, however. It all comes down to which you like the most and which you'd be more comfortable writing with.

Comment: +1. I think a fictional benefit to Norse mythology is that it **is** less familiar, and might be more interesting to readers than a rehash of well-worn Greek mythologies.